# Why does the top displace modifier always switch to the active texture?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

Often when modeling I have a need to apply multiple layers of displacement, with each displace modifier using a different texture.  However, every time I go to the texture panel and select one of the textures the topmost displace modifier (and none of the others) switches to using that texture.  I then must go back to the modifier panel and switch it back, which is a royal pain in the neck to do this every time I go to edit a different texture.

Why does Blender do this?  I don't think it is a bug as I can remember it doing this for as long as I have used Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When selecting the texture to edit, you are actually *setting* the texture to be used by the displace modifier(s) and anything else that was using the texture that was there before you set it.

It's the same with materials:

Say I want to edit the blue material. If I select the blue material with the orange object selected, I'll turn the orange object blue:

[image]

Instead, I should select the blue object:

[image]

I have to select the blue object.

To "select" a texture being used by a displace modifier, either click the button next to the texture slot in the modifier:

[image]

Or in the texture panel, select which *modifier* you want to edit, instead of which texture:

[image]

---

If you want to be able to edit a specific datablock regardless of the object selection, you can *Pin* a panel by clicking the pin:

[image]

This will prevent that panel from displaying another object's datablocks until it is unlocked again.